# WordPress Subpages Fancybox Trouble

Tags: theme-development, jquery

I have a website that I'm converting over from a static html site to WordPress. I got almost everthing done, but I'm having trouble with there "about us" page.  When you click on their profile it opens up a html iframe about their bios.

[The current "about us" page](http://www.venenumbiodesign.com/aboutus.php)

I have created sub pages for the bios in WordPress , but it keeps the current style of the site instead of the style that they have for the bios.  What's the best path I could take to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understand your question correctly, your problem is that your iframes are showing the theme (nav menu, sidebar, etc.) and you don't want them to.

If that's the case, I'd recommend creating a new Page Template that is styled after your bio iframe (no menus, no sidebar).

There's more info on creating custom page templates here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates